# Sql Query to Calculate Performance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have following DB Schema..

```
-- Companies
id
name

--financial_report
id
company_id
quarter (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
fiscal_year (2018, 2017)
revenue
employees
```

I want to get following result for companies based on quarter and fiscal year..

Sample Result for Q3-2018

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+
| CompanyName | Employees | Revenue |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
| Company1    |        12 |  50,000 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9813bf

Thanks

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I will post sqlfiddle in few minutes. Sorry about that..

Comment: what about this `SELECT c.name as CompanyName, fr.employees as Employees, fr.revenue as Revenue from Companies c INNER JOIN financial_report fr WHERE c.id=fr.company_id `

Comment: sqlfiddle posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with `Group By`:

```
SELECT 
  fr.fiscal_year, 
  fr.quarter, 
  c.name AS CompanyName, 
  SUM(fr.employees) AS Employees, 
  SUM(fr.revenue) AS Revenue 
FROM companies AS c 
JOIN financial_reports AS fr ON c.id = fr.company_id
GROUP BY fr.fiscal_year, 
         fr.quarter, 
         c.id
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hd4HfvcsKNhk4x4sWchScq/1)